# Increase precision in pie chart Kibana

Tags: kibana, pie-chart

I have a series of categories, where some of them has a really low occurrence in the data set; but there still data from those categories. This is the data:

```
﻿OS,Count
iOS,2119832
"__missing__",242326
"Windows Phone",122
Windows,28274
Ubuntu,18
Other,4170
"Mac OS X",6641
Linux,348
"Chrome OS",8
Android,12478135
```

You can see that there a lot of data for `Android`, `iOS` and `__missing__` categories and very low numbers for others. This caused the pie chart to just show these three and other are just shown in the `Inspect` and `Label` hint:

[image]

How can I force the chart to show all the categories? May I change the chart type for this?

Comment: Yes, another visualization should work better — maybe a treemap or a bar chart?

Comment: Please check my own answer @xeraa

Answer (score 0):

I used the `Lens` visualization and set the `Stacked Chart` as default. The little numbers are not visible at first sight, but counts are visible when you hover the mouse on each bar and I don't have to inspect the data to see all the categories and their counts.